# Ignore OnClick before OnDblClick

Tags: lazarus

I have a TDBgrid with an OnCellClick event that toggles a Boolean.

I want to be able to launch another Form with a OnDblClick but do not want the OnCellClick to change the Boolean.

Short of programatically calling the OnCellClick to revert the Boolean as part of the OnDblClick handling, is there any way to ignore the OnCellClick when double-clicking?

I do not want a Popup menu or Right-click as this is mostly going to be on touch screen devices.

Comment: GetDoubleClickTime, then fire a timer in OnClick with an interval of DoubleClick+100 ms or so. In OnDoubleClick disable the timer if it is active. Run CellClick when the timer expires.

Comment: Your proposed user interface will be horribly confusing to use. Find a different way.

Comment: Instead of using `OnCellClick`, you should probably consider using something such as `TADOQuery.AfterScroll` and update some variable to know which record it's on. Use that to perform your single click operations instead of actually detecting a single click. Don't do anything for a "single click". Just handle the double click. The scrolling of the dataset is the appropriate trigger for your "single click" task. There's more ways a user can select a record than just a single click. For example, the up/down arrows on the keyboard. Or simply scrolling the mouse wheel on the data grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what TurboPower did in the VisualPlanIt components:

Remove the OnClick handler. Add a timer. Its interval length should be slightly longer than the duration of the double-click, i.e. a few tenths of a second. In the MouseDown event start the timer. In the timer's OnTimer handler disable the timer and perform the action that should occur in the regular OnClick event. If a second click occurs while the timer is active it must be a double-click.

This sequence separates the single from the double click. To me, however, it is a bit disturbing because a normal mouse click sees a reaction only after a short delay.

Answer (score 0):

Or put your form opening on CTRL-Click.